# android emulator launch on mac desktop

Tags: android, macos

I know Android phone emulator seems to only launch to set main display on my M1 MAX Laptop.  (this maybe a limitation in Android Studio??)

Anyone  find a  work around to get it Android emulator to launch onto a set desktop screen on secondary monitor on M1 Mac, other than set main display?

Answer (score 0):

scrcpy is open source screen mirroring application, this might work..!

Please go through this - [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you are just providing a link without any explanation or input from your end, it should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: The answer does not include much input or explanation from the user. It should be a comment instead.